# Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, node-modules

hello I have the following error, I have an app in vuejs, it was working fine, the error appeared suddenly, reinstalled everything, clean cache and I can't find a way to solve it, I hope your help

Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude) in

`````
  "exclude": [
    null
  ],
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "/Users/juanpablo/front-treatments/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js",
      "options": {
        "cacheDirectory": "/Users/juanpablo/front-treatments/node_modules/.cache/babel-loader",
        "cacheIdentifier": "81fef5a6"
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-38[0].rules[0].use[0]"
    },
    {
      "loader": "/Users/juanpablo/front-treatments/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
      "options": "undefined",
      "ident": "undefined"
    }
  ]
} ````
A complete log of this run can be found in:
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/juanpablo/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/juanpablo/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'serve'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.19.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle vue-dashboard@0.1.0~preserve: vue-dashboard@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle vue-dashboard@0.1.0~serve: vue-dashboard@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle vue-dashboard@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vue-dashboard@0.1.0~serve: PATH: /Users/juanpablo/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/juanpablo/front-treatments/node_modules/.bin:/Users/juanpablo/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/juanpablo/.rvm/bin
9 verbose lifecycle vue-dashboard@0.1.0~serve: CWD: /Users/juanpablo/front-treatments
10 silly lifecycle vue-dashboard@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle vue-dashboard@0.1.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vue-dashboard@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: vue-dashboard@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/juanpablo/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/juanpablo/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid vue-dashboard@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/juanpablo/front-treatments
16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/juanpablo/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/bin/node" "/Users/juanpablo/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/bin/npm" "run" "serve"
18 verbose node v12.19.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error vue-dashboard@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vue-dashboard@0.1.0 serve script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
`````

Comment: Hello Juan! Did you get any fix on this problem? I'm encountering the same with the latest version of the vue cli

Comment: I find this sad that the "Fix" was to go back in time.  I would much prefer a way through this issue.

Answer (score 120):

Deleting webpack and installing previous version worked for me!

```
npm uninstall webpack
npm install webpack@^4.0.0 --save-dev
```

Comment: I had the same problem and doing this solved the issue

Comment: It's useful for me.  3Q

Comment: Thanks! Reverting webpack back from 5.11.11 to 4.42.0 worked for me. Any idea why?

Comment: Had this error on the netlify build process running gridsome build.

using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
downgraded webpack from v5 to v4 worked for me.

Comment: Downgrading webpack failed: `npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree`. The solution was to downgrade node from 15 to 14 (`nvm install 14.0.0`) and re-install all packages. See the answer of E.M.

Comment: note in my `vue-cli` generated project I also had to downgrade `vue-loader` to `^14` and `css-loader` to `^4` to resolve compatibility issues in the build process.

Comment: Well I get "npm ERR! premature close" lol

Comment: Thanks this helped me to overcome this error and get to next one.

Answer (score 26):

I encountered exactly this error today, and my solution to fix this was to revert changes in my package-lock.json.

Then a `npm prune` to remove unuseful packages and `npm update` to be up-to-date.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. All the others solved it by reverting. This one fixed the issue with webpack 5 itself

Comment: Didn't have to change a thing, just npm prune / npm update was enough to get it resolved.

Answer (score 9):

I downgraded to `"webpack": "^4.45.0"` and it worked. I changed the line  `"webpack": "^4.45.0"` in `package.json` and after that I run the command `npm update`

Answer (score 8):

my problem was that in package.json it had "webpack": 'latest', this generated conflicts, what I did was go back to version 4.44.0 of webpack and my problem was solved

Answer (score 6):

Probably related to latest Node (version 15) and npm (version 7).

My use case was slightly different but I had the same problem in Dockerfile.
Had to change from `node:alpine` to `node:lts-alpine`

Locally everything worked with Node LTS which uses node 14.15.0 and npm 6.14.8 but Dockerfile was using latest versions.

Comment: I concluded this as well myself on Windows, downgrading from Node version 15 to Node version 14 LTS does the trick :)

Answer (score 6):

These are the highest versions I could achieve on the package.json without triggering the mentioned issue. You can add Vue 2 or 3 and remaining libraries without problems.

**Recommended required versions after npm audit fix**

*Remove 'node-sass' and add 'sass'*

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.21.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.77.0"
},
```

**Minimum required with deprecation warnings**

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.21.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
},
```

After that run `npm update`

Comment: Absolute life-saver, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We had this issue and downgrading webpack didn't want to work because of `css-loader` requiring webpack 5.

Without specifying the version `css-loader` would update to version 5, which doesn't support webpack 3/4.

The solution turned out to be hardcoding `css-loader` to version `3.6.0`:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "3.15.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.20",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.11",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2",
    "vuex-persist": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.14",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.14",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.14",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.14",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "3.6.0"
  }
}
```

The important part here is the `peerDependencies` part. After this make sure to delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, and rerun `npm i`.

Answer (score 2):

the downgrade was fundamental but then I had to downgrade sass-loader.
[TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082397/typeerror-this-getoptions-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

For future investigators on this type of issue:

WebPack version downgrade isn't a good way to go when you for sure need ^5 version. Look carefully at what logs say! In this case it's possibly 'vue-dashboard@0.1.0' that causing the issue. Try upgrading all libraries where you find this error or stop using abandoned ones if upgrade not possible!

Answer (score -1):

Installing [`vue-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-loader) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -12):

For me I was using npm to install, so what I did was:

1. Delete `package-lock.json`
2. Delete `node_modules`
3. Run `yarn install`
4. `yarn serve`, and voilà!