# Why does vue.js not work inside html files?

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I wanted to add Vue.js to my Spring Boot application. Even though everything seem to build fine, I cannot make vue component work.
Here is my simple component, **MenuBar.vue**:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        Menu
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "MenuBar"
}
</script>
```

And here is HTML which should be using it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vueApp">
    <menu-bar></menu-bar>
</div>

<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <div><input type="submit" value="Log out"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Configuration files **index.js**:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.devtools = true;

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: {App}
});

new Vue({
    el: '#vueApp'
})
```

**components.js**:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import MenuBar from "./components/MenuBar";

Vue.component('menu-bar', MenuBar);
```

And webpack config file:

```js
// webpack.config.js
const {VueLoaderPlugin} = require('vue-loader');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.vue', '.js'],
        alias: {
            'components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/')
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        // make sure to include the plugin for the magic
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
        hot: false,
        liveReload: true,
        proxy: {
            "*": {
                target: 'http://localhost:8080',
                ignorePath: false,
                changeOrigin: false,
                secure: false
            }
        },
        port: 8081,
        host: "0.0.0.0"
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/resources/static/dist')
    }
}
```

When I build npm and run application page contains element `<menu-bar></menu-bar>` but does not load its content. What could be an issue here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you add the `component` inside of `<div id="vueApp">` at:

```
<div id="vueApp">
    <menu-bar></menu-bar>
</div>
```

In this case, your app renders inside of this `<div id="vueApp">` tag. Everything you write inside of this tag at your `html` file, will be overwritten.

You have another file named `App.vue`. You should add your `MenuBar.vue` component to this main component and it should show.

---

**EDIT: Easiest attempt to get your component to work**

This ist the `main.js`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

// Create app
const app = createApp(App);

// Import component
import MenuBar from "./components/MenuBar";

// Use MenuBar
app.component('MenuBar', MenuBar);

// Mount app
app.mount('#app')
```

This is the `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <MenuBar></MenuBar>
    Body
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
}
</script>
```

This is the `MenuBar.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Menu
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MenuBar"
}
</script>
```

As we have a slight different approach I will also give you the `package.json`, so you can just hit `npm install` and it should implement all the (few) packages includet in this app:

```
{
  "name": "q68966956",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

It looks like you are in a early stage with your project, so maybe you can start with a stable base from that code. Let me know, if it helped you.

Comment: Tried that. Still does not work. I'm afraid something is wrong with my config :/

Comment: @Bajor I will take your code and edit it until it runs. Then I´ll add it in my answer. Give me some minutes.

Comment: It cannot build for me: 

Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include

Comment: @Bajor You need to create a new project before. Use `vue create Projectname`

Comment: @Bajor Somebody had the same issue: [Error: Rule can only have one resource source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373393/error-rule-can-only-have-one-resource-source-provided-resource-and-test-incl)